# how to config nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx

I want to access to http://serverIP:9000/projects through my domain name. I tried to write the config file like this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xxx.xxx.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myserverip:9000/projects;
    }
}
```

and this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xxx.xxx.com;
    client_max_body_size 90m;
    client_body_timeout  20m;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myserverip:9000/projects;
        proxy_set_header Host      $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

}
```

but it still cannot access to http://myserverip:9000/projects. How should I write the config file to make it right. Thanks!

Comment: what error are you getting, the nginx server can reach your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  can use:

```
proxy_redirect http://xxx.xxx.com http://myserverip:9000/projects;
proxy_redirect off;
server_name_in_redirect off;
```

but make sure CSS's path is right for this.

Or :

```
proxy_pass http://myserverip:9000/;
```

then you can access : `http://xxx.xxx.com/projects`

Comment: I tried the first way, but it always in a loading page, the result is same as my first config...the http://myserverip:9000/projects is accessible

Comment: I write the config like this, is there anything wrong? Still cannot access the /projects page...
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.udache.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myserverip:9000;
        proxy_redirect xxx.xxx.com http://myserverip:9000/projects;
        server_name_in_redirect off;
    }
}

Comment: Just use `proxy_redirect` only, `proxy_pass` is other case

Comment: Done! Thank you!